# Copying pytorch model to GPU is much slower in docker?

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to DiffusionPipeline to generate images. I want to work in Docker for portability, isolation, reproducible setup, etc. My OS is Windows 10. My base docker image is "pytorch/pytorch:latest". My issue is the 'to("cuda")' command is taking 6X longer in the Docker environment (3-4 min) as does on the host machine.

Within the Docker environment, I run the following code:

```
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline
import transformers
import torch
import os
from global_config import global_config

from torch.profiler import profile, record_function, ProfilerActivity

# Added to try to speed things up from:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464643/performance-issues-with-machine-learning-using-docker-and-flask 
torch.set_num_threads(1)

print("Torch version:", torch.__version__)

print("Is CUDA enabled?", torch.cuda.is_available())

print(f"torch version: {torch.version.cuda}")

generator = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(
    "runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5", cache_dir=global_config.model_dir()
)

with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("model_inference"):
        generator.to("cuda")

t = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory
r = torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0)
a = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)
f = r-a  # free inside reserved
print(f'total (MB)    : {t/1e6}')
print(f'free (MB)     : {f/1e6}')
print(f'allocated (MB) : {a/1e6}')
print(f'reserved (MB) : {r/1e6}')


print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="cpu_time_total", row_limit=10))
```

The full output is as follows:

```
(base) root@22010904699b:/workspace# /opt/conda/bin/python /workspace/src/main.py
Torch version: 2.0.1
Is CUDA enabled? True
torch version: 11.7
device name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
`text_config_dict` is provided which will be used to initialize `CLIPTextConfig`. The value `text_config["id2label"]` will be overriden.
`text_config_dict` is provided which will be used to initialize `CLIPTextConfig`. The value `text_config["bos_token_id"]` will be overriden.
`text_config_dict` is provided which will be used to initialize `CLIPTextConfig`. The value `text_config["eos_token_id"]` will be overriden.
WARNING:2023-07-25 04:05:31 718:718 init.cpp:146] function cbapi->getCuptiStatus() failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED (15)
WARNING:2023-07-25 04:05:31 718:718 init.cpp:147] CUPTI initialization failed - CUDA profiler activities will be missing
INFO:2023-07-25 04:05:31 718:718 init.cpp:149] If you see CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES, refer to https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err-nvgpuctrperm-cupti
STAGE:2023-07-25 04:05:31 718:718 ActivityProfilerController.cpp:311] Completed Stage: Warm Up
STAGE:2023-07-25 04:11:16 718:718 ActivityProfilerController.cpp:317] Completed Stage: Collection
STAGE:2023-07-25 04:11:16 718:718 ActivityProfilerController.cpp:321] Completed Stage: Post Processing
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 50/50 [00:21<00:00,  2.30it/s]
-------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                                       Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls  
-------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
                            model_inference         0.26%     886.103ms       100.00%      344.795s      344.795s             1  
                                   aten::to         0.01%      18.660ms        99.74%      343.899s     225.065ms          1528  
                             aten::_to_copy         0.01%      33.231ms        99.74%      343.889s     225.058ms          1528  
                                aten::copy_        94.98%      327.473s        94.98%      327.473s     214.315ms          1528  
                        aten::empty_strided         4.75%       16.383s         4.75%       16.383s      10.722ms          1528  
    aten::_has_compatible_shallow_copy_type         0.00%     897.000us         0.00%     897.000us       0.294us          3052  
-------------------------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
Self CPU time total: 344.795s
```

The 'generator.to("cuda")' command takes over 3 minutes in Docker, while it is under 30 seconds if I run this the function on the host machine. Is this disparity in runtime reasonable? Are other people finding doing machine learning in Docker makes allocation much slower or is this something that can be fixed?

**Edit:**

RAM usage inside Docker:

```
total (MB)    : 8589.672448
free (MB)     : 88.072192
allocated (MB) : 5507.129344
reserved (MB) : 5595.201536
```

Outside of Docker:

```
total (MB)    : 8589.672448
free (MB)     : 129.753088
allocated (MB) : 5499.002880
reserved (MB) : 5628.755968
```

free=allocated-reserved. Extra instrumentation added to code above.

I also used `nvidia-smi -l 5' outside of container to watch memory allocation in each case. The maximum usage reported by this command was roughly "6903MiB /  8192MiB" in both cases. Running the python code outside of the container, this maximum was quickly reached. When I ran the python code in Docker, the memory allocation was gradual: the allocation slowly rose over a few minutes before it hit this maximum.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you check how much RAM is being used in both cases?

Comment: Thanks! I added some info on memory usage collected with `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()`.

Comment: If your host had been Linux, this would be surprising, since a Docker container _on Linux_ is using the exact same interfaces the host does, just from a set of namespaces with constrained access privileges. On Windows, it's... much less surprising.